# Docker Laravel Container Throwing [pid X] AH00052: child pid XXXX exit signal Segmentation fault (11) when PhpStorm Xdebug Listening is Turned On

Tags: laravel, docker, xdebug

I have a strange situation happening on my M3 Macbook Pro that is preventing me from debugging a particular Docker container.

This worked without hitches on my previous M2 Macbook Pro.

My workflow is to use PhpStorm for a Laravel API repo. Here are the environment options from the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
    environment:
      APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/www/html/public/
      PHP_EXTENSION_XDEBUG: 1
      PHP_EXTENSION_MONGODB: 1
      PHP_EXTENSION_JSON: 1
      PHP_EXTENSION_GD: 1
      PHP_EXTENSION_PDO_SQLITE: 1
      PHP_INI_MEMORY_LIMIT: 256M
      PHP_INI_XDEBUG__MODE: "develop,debug"
      PHP_INI_XDEBUG__CLIENT_HOST: "host.docker.internal"
      PHP_INI_XDEBUG__START_WITH_REQUEST: "${XDEBUG:-yes}"
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=app.local"
```

When the container is started with `XDEBUG` set to `yes`, I can send requests to my API and the application handles them, no problem. But when I toggle debug listening in PhpStorm, the process inside the container inevitable fails with  variant of the following message:

```
[core:notice] [pid 7] AH00052: child pid 2764 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

This is preventing my from using the debugger entirely.

Here are the resources I've allocated to the Docker engine:

[image: docker resources]